# Alarm Manager isn't repeating after reboot

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have problem with Alarm Manager. I create alarm manager which repeat displaying toast every 15 seconds.

After rebooting my device, toast is visible, but only once. I want to repeat it again every 15 seconds even after reboot.

What can I add to solve this? Is this possible?

Here is my code (class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR TAG");
    //Acquire the lock
    wl.acquire();

    Toast.makeText(context, "wow", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //Release the lock
    wl.release();

}

 public void SetAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 15000, pi);
}
```

And my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".view.activity.AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

EDIT: The solve of this problem is edit code in onReceiver():

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction()==null){
        Toast.makeText(context, "lol", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else
    {
        AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent1, 0);
        am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 15000, pi);
    }

}
```

Comment: Since your Alarm Intent is calling the Receiver explicitly, you don't need a custom action. Just check if the Intent action is null in `onReceive()`. If it is, show the Toast; otherwise call your method to set the Alarm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you simply need to call your SetAlarm function in the onReceive Method, and listen for the sent event in your manifest.

In your manifest

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
   //New
   <action android:name="com.packagename.custombroadcast" />
</intent-filter>
```

As your intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.packagename.custombroadcast");
//Use Context.sendBroadcast
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Ok, I thought about it, but I hoped that maybe there will be better solution to achieve this. Thank you for answer ;-)